# Set a Cookie programmatically in a Crosswalk WebView on Android

Tags: android, session-cookies, crosswalk

I need to save a Cookie in my Crosswalk webview which i have received via a HttpsUrlConnection. 
This is how i have initialized my Crosswalk web view.

```
private XWalkView xWalkWebView;
private XWalkCookieManager cookieManager;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    xWalkWebView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xweb_View);

    cookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
    cookieManager.setCookie("http://abc.xyz.com","Authorization=access_token");
}
```

I need to bind the cookies within the cookieManager to the above XwalkView object.
I would really appreciate any help regarding my requirement.

Best Regards,

Mujee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try to use httpRequestExecutor.setXWalkCookieManager(cookieManager);
like it described in
http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/e8eab567179b/set-cookies-programatically-in-crosswalk-webview-on-android.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I tried this. But couldn't find a way to bind the XWalkCookieManager object with XWalkView.